# C - Representation of a matrix as a linked list

Tags: c, matrix, linked-list

I have the following data structure:

[image]

that represents a matrix as a linked list.

I need to add a new row of the matrix at the bottom and initialize the values of that list with zeros.

**Question:** Is it possible to use singly list with two links for each node? That way, we can add a new list at the bottom with horizontal pointers (links).

But I don't understand how to link the vertical pointers (links) with the next list.

Could someone explain how to link vertical pointers of the bottom list?

Comment: That diagram is definitely not an array of anything.  I guess you could describe it as 2D linked list.

Comment: Why do think a 2D linked list a good data structure for a matrix?

Comment: @Oliver Charlesworth You say that this data structure can be described as 2D linked list, but wouldn't it mean that it can be flattened? It seems that this can't be flattened.

Comment: That might make sense for a sparese matrix, i.e. with few non-zero entries. It requires additional information, though. As shown there seems to be little sense. But as you don't tell us what you want, we can't help further and your question is not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question, then yes its possible, and you can do so iteratively using a pointer-to-pointer and *forward chaining*, a common technique for building linked lists in input-traversal order.

Given a node structure like this:

```
struct Node
{
    struct Node *up;
    struct Node *right;
    int value;
};
```

You can hang a one-for-one matching node across the bottom of the "matrix" (meaning, your current bottom row has N nodes, the added row will likewise have N nodes) by doing this:

```
struct Node *addRow(struct Node *mat)
{
    struct Node *res = NULL, **pp = &res;
    for (; mat; mat = mat->right)
    {
        *pp = malloc(sizeof **pp);
        (*pp)->value = 0;
        (*pp)->up = mat;
        pp = &(*pp)->right;
    }
    *pp = NULL;
    return res;
}
```

This works by walking a pointer-to-pointer through the list being created, always having it address the pointer that will be set to point to with the next new node. When the list is complete, the final `right` pointer must be set to NULL to terminate the right-chained list (`*pp = NULL;` accomplishes this).

Execution simply becomes

```
mat = addRow(mat);
```

That's it.

Answer (score 1):

Use recursion:

To add row to `NULL` (representing empty table) return `NULL` (empty table).

To add row to `non-NULL` element `bottomLeft`:

1. Create new element `newNode`
2. Link `up pointer` of `newNode` to `bottomLeft`
3. Append row to `bottomLeft->right` save that row as `right pointer` of `newNode`.
4. Set value to `0`
5. Return `newNode`

Example:

```
struct Node;

struct Node {
    struct Node *up;
    struct Node *right;
    int value;
};

struct Node *addRow(struct Node *bottomLeft) {
    if(bottomLeft == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    } else {
        struct Node* newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        newNode->value = 0;
        newNode->up = bottomLeft;
        newNode->right = addRow(bottomLeft->right);
        return newNode;
    }
}
```